# Laptop screen as a PC monitor?

Tags: display, laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Laptop Screen as a monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/87048/using-laptop-screen-as-a-monitor)

I have a PC and a laptop. My monitor is currently broken and I want to use my laptop's screen for my PC. I can stick my monitor cable into the laptop but I don't know how to make it work.

Laptop is running on windows 7 and PC on XP. Basically I want to work on my PC and see results on the laptop screen. Is that even possible, and if it is, how??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Laptop Screen as a monitor](http://superuser.com/questions/87048/using-laptop-screen-as-a-monitor) and/or [How can I use my laptop's monitor as my PC's ONLY monitor?](http://superuser.com/questions/143833/how-can-i-use-my-laptops-monitor-as-my-pcs-only-monitor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this.  The vga socket on your laptop is for output, not for input.  You can do Laptop->Monitor but not PC->Laptop Screen.

Comment: Ah that sucks :/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the best you could do is make a remote desktop or vnc connection from the laptop to the PC. There's not a single laptop on the market right now that's built to support this.

Even if you wanted to physically remove the display from your laptop for use with your desktop, laptop displays typically use different signaling mechanisms and you'd still need to purchase an adapter board, and this is a far from turn-key solution (there's no generic product on the market right now that supports this - you have to know which components you need).

Comment: Remote desktop should come very close with a decent network connection for your average computer tasks, though it would  likely have problems with anything graphics intensive like gaming.

Answer (score -2):

I think "windows key"+P is the shortcut to hook up to a projector. See if that switches over to the monitor hooked up?

Comment: Oop nevermind, read it backwards

Comment: Since you know you read the question incorrectly, you should either delete your answer or edit it to actually answer the question.